# NULL response from AWS Lambda - get ec2 volumes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to get the list of volumes attached to the instances. The console shows that there is no error in the code but I get a NULL response.

Could you please help me understand the problem?

```
import boto3 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    region = "ap-southeast-2"  
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name=region)  
    available_volumes = ec2.volumes.all()
print(available_volumes)
```

Comment: Have you tried with no (empty) filters. Maybe nothing is matching.

Comment: Tried this " available_volumes = ec2.volumes.all() " and still the same : a NULL response.

Comment: Code indentation is wrong, please correct. And where is the code that calls get_available_volumes()?

Comment: Sorry! Still learning stuff while doing. I've edited the code. Please have a look.

Comment: `us-southeast-2a` is not a region, it's an availability zone.  The region would be `ap-southeast-2`.

Answer (score 0):

In boto3, [collections](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/collections.html) provide an iterable interface to a group of resources. There is a big difference between a list and an iterable in Python.

Here is an example of iteration:

```
import boto3 
ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")  
for volume in ec2.volumes.all():
    print(volume)
```

If you want them as a list, then do this:

```
import boto3 
ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")
volumes = list(ec2.volumes.all())
print(volumes)
```

Comment: Just did as advised. I got the below error : {
  "errorMessage": "2018-03-20T23:47:49.771Z 175561ac-2c99-11e8-b2b6-21a2781a6575 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Comment: Lambda functions have a default timeout of 3 seconds. You can increase this in the Lambda function configuration. You can also increase the RAM associated with the Lambda function and that will increase the CPU proportionally, and make the code run faster. That said, I encourage you to do a small amount of research when you run into new problems rather than rely on iterative debugging attempts via Stack Overflow.